# Very slow boot with Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and it boots very slow after I deleted my swap partition, more than ***100 seconds*** with SSD disk. I tried to upgrade to newer kernel, but it did not help me. What do you suggest?.

Thank you.

Here is a part of my dmesg output: (I cannot past it whole because of body limit on stackoverflow. )

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.0.5-040005-generic (kernel@gloin) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #201506061639 SMP Sat Jun 6 16:40:45 UTC 2015
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.5-040005-generic root=UUID=346acb51-2771-4509-9386-3975b2299b5b ro quiet splash
 ...
[    8.413878] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    8.413884] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    8.413891] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    8.413896] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    8.414255] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    8.414426] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    8.414437] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    8.414472] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    8.414485] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    8.415363] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    8.415743] systemd[1]: Started Read required files in advance.
[    8.415913] systemd[1]: Starting Read required files in advance...
[    8.416413] systemd[1]: Starting Nameserver information manager...
[    8.416881] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    8.417332] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    8.419537] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    8.419936] systemd[1]: Starting Setup Virtual Console...
[    8.420408] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[    8.420996] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    8.421496] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    8.421895] systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set keymap...
[    8.422352] systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
[    8.422433] systemd[1]: Starting Braille Device Support...
[    8.422466] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    8.422479] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    8.422530] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    8.422541] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    8.423567] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    8.424174] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    8.424196] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    8.424212] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    8.424392] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
[    8.425071] systemd[1]: Started Setup Virtual Console.
[    8.425473] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    8.425483] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    8.425885] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    8.426632] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    8.427633] systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
[    8.427966] systemd[1]: Started Nameserver information manager.
[    8.435242] systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set keymap.
[    8.443693] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    8.444824] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    8.447911] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    8.459157] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    8.459268] systemd[1]: Mounted Configuration File System.
[    8.459641] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    8.460047] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    8.460339] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    8.565394] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    8.568655] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    8.573815] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[    8.573817] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[    8.573818] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS H0ET95WW (2.55 ), EC unknown
[    8.573819] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E530, model 627247G
[    8.574431] thinkpad_acpi: Unsupported brightness interface, please contact ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
[    8.574556] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    8.574557] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    8.576135] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    8.584756] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input10
[    8.587833] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587840] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.587844] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587848] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587852] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.587854] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587858] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587862] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.587863] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587867] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO) (20150204/utaddress-254)
[    8.587871] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    8.587873] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    8.589126] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    8.611507] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    8.638025] sound hdaudioC0D0: CX20590: BIOS auto-probing.
[    8.638499] sound hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20590: line_outs=1 (0x1f/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.638502] sound hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.638505] sound hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x19/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.638507] sound hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.638508] sound hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    8.638511] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x23
[    8.638513] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1a
[    8.639336] sound hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[    8.653096] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    8.653191] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    8.653282] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    8.659836] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    8.660489] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    8.660492] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    8.675350] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    8.675368] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    8.675370] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.675375] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.675378] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.675383] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.678744] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    8.678748] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    8.679216] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    8.681881] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    8.685721] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21f4.hcd failed with error -2
[    8.685727] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21f4.hcd not found
[    8.689387] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150204/nsarguments-95)
[    8.689494] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150204/nsarguments-95)
[    8.689586] pci 0000:01:00.0: optimus capabilities: enabled, status dynamic power, 
[    8.689591] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP handle
[    8.689631] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0007)
[    8.702541] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    8.702544] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    8.702648] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    8.726637] ACPI: Video Device [VID] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    8.726777] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input14
[    8.726836] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, Evaluating _DOD (20150204/video-1257)
[    8.726840] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: no  rom: yes  post: no)
[    8.726868] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:43/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input15
[    8.726907] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20150130 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    8.727280] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x0c1180a1
[    8.727282] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] Chipset: GF108 (NVC1)
[    8.727283] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] Family : NVC0
[    8.744835] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    8.748169] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    8.748172] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    8.748174] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    8.772379] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] using image from ACPI
[    8.772468] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] BIT signature found
[    8.772470] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] version 70.08.aa.00.10
[    8.773115] nouveau  [ DEVINIT][0000:01:00.0] adaptor not initialised
[    8.773122] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] running init tables
[    8.880714] nouveau  [     PMC][0000:01:00.0] MSI interrupts enabled
[    8.880739] nouveau W[     PFB][0000:01:00.0][0x00000000] reclocking of this ram type unsupported
[    8.880740] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:01:00.0] RAM type: DDR3
[    8.880741] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:01:00.0] RAM size: 1024 MiB
[    8.880741] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:01:00.0]    ZCOMP: 0 tags
[    8.882462] nouveau  [    VOLT][0000:01:00.0] GPU voltage: 912500uv
[    8.911542] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:01:00.0] FAN control: none / external
[    8.911556] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:01:00.0] fan management: automatic
[    8.911576] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:01:00.0] internal sensor: yes
[    8.931465] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] 07: core 270 MHz memory 405 MHz 
[    8.931469] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] 0f: core 660 MHz memory 900 MHz 
[    8.931616] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] --: core 270 MHz memory 405 MHz 
[    8.934906] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[    8.935026] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 3881818 kiB
[    8.935027] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[    8.935027] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    8.935033] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    8.935041] nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 1024 MiB
[    8.935042] nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
[    8.935045] nouveau  [     DRM] TMDS table version 2.0
[    8.935045] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
[    8.935047] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 00: 02001300 00000000
[    8.935048] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 01: 00000100
[    8.935571] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    8.935571] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    8.941047] nouveau  [     DRM] MM: using COPY0 for buffer copies
[    8.986814] nouveau  [     DRM] allocated 1024x768 fb: 0x60000, bo ffff880253d19400
[    9.040786] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    9.040973] [drm:cpt_set_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[    9.040990] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[    9.324204] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input9
[    9.470718] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    9.472408] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    9.472410] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[    9.472553] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb1: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[    9.472556] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: registered panic notifier
[    9.485385] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.2.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    9.733524] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    9.746835] systemd-journald[278]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    9.765118] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.908:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.765124] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.908:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="chromium" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.767870] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.908:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.767875] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.908:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.767878] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.908:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.767882] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.908:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.779990] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.920:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.779996] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.920:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="sanitized_helper" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.779999] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.920:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.780001] audit: type=1400 audit(1434985961.920:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="sanitized_helper" pid=619 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.839488] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150204/nsarguments-95)
[   14.839554] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   14.839557] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150204/nsarguments-95)
[   38.489638] usb 4-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   38.593295] usb 4-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=05ca, idProduct=1823
[   38.593304] usb 4-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   38.593308] usb 4-1.6: Product: Integrated Camera
[   38.593311] usb 4-1.6: Manufacturer: C6JC9O01D
[   38.607025] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   38.610894] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   38.618621] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (05ca:1823)
[   38.620261] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.6/4-1.6:1.0/input/input16
[   38.620310] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   38.620311] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   98.341860] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   98.377621] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   98.377623] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   98.377627] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   98.385334] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   98.385341] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   98.385347] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   98.396956] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   98.403318] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   98.403323] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   98.403324] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   98.403327] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   98.403330] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   98.403332] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   98.403334] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   98.403336] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   98.669480] r8169 0000:0c:00.0 eth0: link down
[  103.922732] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  103.925608] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores.
[  103.925788] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x1a0 offMax=0x1b95
[  103.925889] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
[  103.925891] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.26_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a000a).
[  103.937818] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[  121.263475] usb 3-1.4: usbfs: process 1271 (FingerprintDevi) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  123.127401] show_signal_msg: 36 callbacks suppressed
[  123.127407] indicator-ipmac[1739]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f1c3fc8e6fa sp 00007ffcb2618d38 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f1c3fc03000+1c0000]
[  159.126699] usb 3-1.4: usbfs: process 4806 (FingerprintDevi) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  159.930573] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4313, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
[  159.930602] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x24, class 0x0)
[  159.930625] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x18, class 0x0)
[  159.930669] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[  159.943175] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[  159.952324] brcmsmac bcma0:1: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 17
[  159.958258] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[  159.958617] ieee80211 phy0: registered radio enabled led device: brcmsmac-phy0:radio gpio: 499
[  160.077879] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[  160.077889] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[  167.412368] wlan0: authenticate with 64:7c:34:39:eb:02
[  167.418694] wlan0: send auth to 64:7c:34:39:eb:02 (try 1/3)
[  167.420504] wlan0: authenticated
[  167.423796] wlan0: associate with 64:7c:34:39:eb:02 (try 1/3)
[  167.430304] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 64:7c:34:39:eb:02 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  167.430926] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[  167.430930] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  167.430937] wlan0: associated
[  167.430991] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: SK
[  167.433006] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: SK
[  167.433009] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[  167.433010] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  167.433011] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  167.433013] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  167.433014] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  167.433015] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[  167.433016] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[  167.435921] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 159/256 dur 1778/1504
[  167.443320] brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 137/256 dur 1602/1504
[  167.520873] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
```

Comment: check this command: systemd-analyze blame. It should show where the problem is

Answer (score 16):

Its because now there is a reference  in /etc/fstab referring to a non-existent disk. Delete this reference you would be good to go.

EKS:

```
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=52509e-2007-41f1-a3bc-61b529d794 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a3e2dfa3-af33-407e-90d5-5e181137df /media/2TB/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

to:

```
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
```

Comment: How did you figure that out ?

Comment: Lucky guess :)! No I think I answered someone ells-es question in the wrong thread...

Comment: Thanks Mate, You are a life saver. I only wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: If anyone's looking at this who moved/recreated the partition instead of/after  deleting, I installed GParted and looked up the new UUID by right-clicking on the new swap partition and selecting "Information" at the bottom, then replaced the old UUID with the new. I imagine it's probably best to keep the entry in there if the partition still exists.

Comment: This might be in /var/log/boot.log