# Ubuntu 16.04 Slow boot due to bluetooth

Tags: boot, 16.04, bluetooth, dmesg

My ASUS UX305 boots very slow on ubuntu 16.04, and obviously it is due to bluetooth. 
Here is the dmesg output :

`[    8.784060] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc8e tx timeout
[    8.784060] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc8e tx timeout
[    8.784115] Bluetooth: hci0 sending frame failed (-19)
[   10.788137] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc11 tx timeout
[   16.780341] Bluetooth: hci0 exiting Intel manufacturer mode failed (-110)
[   96.823524] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3`

It use to boot very fast and still boots fast on windows.

I tried to rfkill blutooth but did not work

Anyone has a clue what the problem could be ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've solved my problem, it was due to a corrupted patition tha the OS was unable to mount and waited 1.5min to boot. The bluetooth seems to start well since then but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem (Slow start-up and dmesg's output pointing to Bluetooth for some reason.) after resizing partitions using Gparted on Ubuntu 16.04 to accommodate a dual-boot with Windows 10.

In the process to configure the dual boot the swap partition was deleted and recreated, but the UUID variable on `/etc/fstab` kept pointing to the deleted partition. Once I fixed this, the start-up time went back to normal.

I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639559/very-slow-boot-with-ubuntu-15-04.).