# Ubuntu loads at the same speed on SSD as on HDD

Tags: 16.04, ssd

I have changed HDD (WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3T0) for SSD (WDS500G2B0A) in my notebook and found that it loads at the same speed (not faster as I was expecting).

Why?

I copied partitions 1:1, may be I also need to change some settings?

---

By "speed" I mean cold boot time.

---

Here is part of `dmesg` output:

```
[    9.107913] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    9.197366] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.730:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.197377] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.730:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" p
id=845 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.198964] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.730:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.198974] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.730:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.198980] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.730:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.198987] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.730:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=844 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.201702] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.734:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=843 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.201712] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.734:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=843 comm="apparmor_pars
er"
[    9.204268] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.734:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=853 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.204279] audit: type=1400 audit(1538597657.734:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=853 comm="a
pparmor_parser"
[   97.452870] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   97.452876] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
```

As you see, it does nothing for 90 seconds. What does it do?

Comment: I have HDD and SSD. Recently I swapped them between 2 pcs of mine.. I saw the difference.

Comment: Open GNOME Disks and run Benchmark on new SSD drive and you will feel the difference. You wrote "same speed" - what do you mean? Boot time? File copying/moving operations? Speed of first cold start of applications (for example LibreOffice)? How did you configure drive in BIOS - as AHCI or as IDE? Specs comparison shows that drives are [completely different (in Russian)](https://www.nix.ru/price/compare_goods.html?goods_for_compare=158401,330800#tab=compare-properties) - upto 500 Mb/s on R/W are expected :)

Comment: By "speed" I mean cold boot time. This is the question: why the speed is the same while specs are not?

Comment: could it be that your HDD had some flash memory it used to accelerate it? How long does your system need to boot? 10s 1min, 10min? (Grub to graphical login) If your SSD is faster (which you could benchmark), this means that the boot time is dominated by sth else, e.g. waiting for a network connection

Comment: @mbeyss is it possible to measure it?

Comment: Both have a SATA (III) 6.0Gb/s interface.

Comment: Especially on laptops there are several factors that limit overall speed. If your HDD I/O channel bandwidth is maxed out, a faster SDD won't improve overall performance. For example, on my 8-core I5 laptop I can run Handbrake (to encode DVD video to MKV files) on all 8 cores, but CPU load maxes out at around 75-80% because data throughput is the limiting factor.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/639559/very-slow-boot-with-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had swap partition defined in `fstab`. I didn't create it on SSD.

Solved according to this link https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325129

Now it boots instantly.